# auto collapse html content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Perhaps you can help me.
I want to auto create **jquerymobile collapses** (http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible.html) with javascript contents, like this :

```
<h3>title 1</h3>
some text

<h3>title 2</h3>
some text

<h3>title 3</h3>
some text
```

This content come from JSON that I can't manipulate before.
I must wrap each :

```
<h3>title</h3>
some text
```

with this :

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"></div>
```

But it doesn't work... Help !

Comment: you say you can't do this, have you tried yet? sounds to me like you have.   either paste some code, or share a jsfiddle!

Comment: "Perhaps you can't help me" :'(

Comment: corrected with "can" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Html

```
<h3 class="collapse" data-target="content1">Head 1</h3>
<div class="hidden" id="content1"></div>

<h3 class="collapse">Head 2</h3>
<div class="hidden" id="content2"></div>

<h3 class="collapse">Head 3</h3>
<div class="hidden" id="content3"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".collapse").each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    el.click(function(){
        var id = el.attr("data-target");
        // files same names with id's
        $("#"+ id).load("ajax/"+ id +".html");
        // or
        $("#"+ id).load("ajax.php", function(responseText){
            $("#"+ id).html(responseText);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but like i said i can't modify html directly it's a extern JSON source ! I must change it with javascript si impossible to have any other class or div.

Comment: why use ajax?  Why not just set the attributes to hidden or not hidden as needed?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the source code of this page, i can notice that jQuery is adding and removing classes dinamically based on click events. Wrap your content into a div and with jQuery, dinamically add and remove classes. Something like

```
<h3 id="collpase-bar" class="collapsed">Collapse Title</h3>
<div class="collapsible-content hidden">Content</div>
```

Use jQuery functions to handle the click event on collapse title and change to this

```
<h3 id="collapse-bar" class="not-collapsed">Collapse Title</h3>
<div class="collapsible-content shown">Content</div>
```

That's a quick explanation, i'm going to make a fiddle exemplifying that ;)

Comment: The really problem it's to wrap this content in different parts with jquery.

Comment: Done! http://jsfiddle.net/DDxZ6/
You can add some cool jQuery stuff like fadeIn/fadeOut, slideIn/slideOut... To use it with lots of contents, you can actually make use of classes to change the button style and recognize the content to be shown via id or value

Answer (score -1):

It can be help for you : http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default. Meanwhile I understand, you want to create collapsible sections.

Comment: It's jquery no jquery mobile !